# CSS flexbox: Header, main, footer layout. Main part collapsing in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have a simplest situation with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
</head>

<body>
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

So I want my header to be say .. 15%, my footer 5% and my main part taking the rest of the space in the middle.
I can do it with position fixed and all that but I am trying to figure out the flex boxes.
So all my attempts don't work.
According to this article: [Flexbox layout](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/12/application-layout-with-css3-flexible-box-module/) I should have it as simple as this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    height: 75px;
}

main {
    flex: auto;
}

footer {
    height: 25px;
}
```

... but this just does not work. I tried changing sizes from pixels to percentage - no luck. The middle part just collapses and it does not stretch.

I also tried few other examples within the first page of Google hits. Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong. How can I achieve the above with flex boxes?

Thanks.

P.S. Almost forgot. My browser is Chromium 34.0.1847.116 (260972)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't know how you where trying to this method out, but it's working (now at least).

[Here's a JSFiddle showing the layout](http://jsfiddle.net/aJPw7/) - I added a subtle background-color to illustrate the stretch.

```
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    height: 75px;
}

main {
    flex: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

footer {
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: In addition, don't forget to set `overflow:auto` on `main` or the footer will be pushed down if the content of main becomes too large

Comment: Doesn't work. If you stick content in `main`, then the footer goes off the page. Instead, `main` should scroll its content. Demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/akjoqr6u/