# Fixed header needs to stay at top, fixed footer needs to stay at bottom, remaining amount of space fills main div with content

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Here is what the HTML portion of my code looks like. I am using bootstrap to create the grid like layout. Here is an example image of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

As you can see the NAV BAR and FOOTER need to be contained within the left container so that the SIDEBAR on the right also shows up and so they don't overlap the sidebar.

```html
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 ml-2 main">
          <div className="col-md-8">
            <nav>
              <div className="row mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 ml-2 nav">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <div className="ui buttons">
                    <button className="ui button mb-1 mt-1">
                      <i className="plus icon"></i>
                      Add Card
                    </button>
                    <div className="or mb-1 mt-1"></div>
                    <button className="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1">
                      <i className="sort amount down icon"></i>
                      Sort All
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>

              <div className="row mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 ml-2 body">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <div className="card mt-2 mb-2">
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <p className="card-text">{getRandomNumber(0, 101)}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            <footer>
              <div className="row mb-4 mr-2 ml-2">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <h3 className="text-center text-muted">Footer</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </footer>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <ul>
              <h6>React Coding Challenge Formatted Instructions:</h6>
              <li className="list-item">
                Create a responsive React application using either JavaScript or
                TypeScript.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The main portion of the application will contain a list of cards
                with a randomly generated number between 0-100 within each card.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The right pane has a fixed-width that remains attached to the
                right side when the user resizes the window. Once the browser
                width is small, the pane will be hidden.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The top pane is a fixed-heigth toolbar that has a button to add
                additional cards as well as a button to sort all the cards in
                ascending numerical order based on the number within each card.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The bottom pane is a fixed-heigth footer that just contains the
                text "footer".
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The center pane is the card container. It starts out with zero
                cards. The user will click the "Add Card" button in the top
                toolbar to add a card in the center container.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The center pane has a vertical scrollbar that will become
                visible once enough cards are displayed. The user can use the
                scrollbar to scroll through all the added cards.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                The cards are added vertically into rows which will wrap as
                needed. The amount of visible cards per row is dependant on the
                width of the browser.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                Each card has a set pixel size of 300 pixels in width and 250
                pixels in heigth.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                Upon instantiation of a new card, a random number will be
                generated between 0 and 100 and then displayed in the center of
                each new card.
              </li>
              <li className="list-item">
                Each card has a button present in the top-right corner that the
                user may click to remove the card.
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need my footer to be positioned to the bottom of the parent div. The parent div is the main row containing all other divs nested. I've reviewed multiple stackoverflow solutions including relative, absolute css classes. Setting the bottom to 0 px, using margins. I'm not sure where else to go with it. I need the toolbar to remain at the top always, the center portion to fill the rest of the portion of the container and the footer to remain to the bottom. The Toolbar (header) and footer are fixed height, the center portions size should be the remaining amount of space. It also has a sidebar that is fixed as well.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 ml-2 main">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="row mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 ml-2">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="ui buttons">
                <button class="ui button mb-1 mt-1">
                  <i class="plus icon"></i>
                  Add Card
                </button>
                <div class="or mb-1 mt-1"></div>
                <button class="ui positive button mb-1 mt-1">
                  <i class="sort amount down icon"></i>
                  Sort All
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mt-2 mb-2 mr-2 ml-2">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card mt-2 mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-header">Card title</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">Card content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">Card footer</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-4 mr-2 ml-2 footer">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3 class="text-center text-muted">
                Footer
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <ul>
            <lh>React Coding Challenge Formatted Instructions:</lh>
            <li class="list-item">Create a responsive React application using either JavaScript or TypeScript.</li>
            <li class="list-item">The main portion of the application will contain a list of cards with a randomly generated number between 0-100 within each card.</li>
            <li class="list-item">The right pane has a fixed-width that remains attached to the right side when the user resizes the window.
            Once the browser width is small, the pane will be hidden.</li>
            <li class="list-item">The top pane is a fixed-heigth toolbar that has a button to add additional cards as well as a button to sort all the cards
            in ascending numerical order based on the number within each card.</li>
            <li class="list-item">The bottom pane is a fixed-heigth footer that just contains the text "footer".</li>
            <li class="list-item">The center pane is the card container. It starts out with zero cards. The user will click the "Add Card" button in the top toolbar
            to add a card in the center container.</li>
            <li class="list-item">The center pane has a vertical scrollbar that will become visible once enough cards are displayed. The user can use the scrollbar to
            scroll through all the added cards.</li>
            <li class="list-item">The cards are added vertically into rows which will wrap as needed. The amount of visible cards per row is dependant on the 
            width of the browser.</li>
            <li class="list-item">Each card has a set pixel size of 300 pixels in width and 250 pixels in heigth.</li>
            <li class="list-item">Upon instantiation of a new card, a random number will be generated between 0 and 100 and then displayed in the center of each
            new card.</li>
            <li class="list-item">Each card has a button present in the top-right corner that the user may click to remove the card.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can this help solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065699/9718549

Comment: I attempted this but it did not solve the issue. I am using Bootstrap as well and am housing everything in divs. I'm not sure if that changes anything but I'm willing to try anything at this point as I have been messing with this thing for a couple hours now with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Different Header And Footer Styles

There are four different code snippets in this answer, each of which demonstrate different Header and Footer behavior as listed below:

- Sticky Header & Sticky Footer
- Sticky Header & Fixed Footer
- Fixed Header & Sticky Footer
- Fixed Header & Fixed Footer

You can click on the cards to delete them, so that you can see the behavior when there are less cards. You can also visualize this by toggling the window width.

> ### Sticky Header & Sticky Footer

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const container = document.querySelector(".card-container");

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.innerText = "Click Me!!";
    container.appendChild(card);
}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        card.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: cursive;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /*Expanding to take full width*/
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    /*Expanding to take full width*/
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header,
footer {
    background: slateblue;
    padding: 1em;
}

.card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
    place-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 5em 1em; /* Top Padding Is Required */
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: coral;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>Sticky Header & Sticky Footer</header>
<div class="card-container"></div>
<footer>Sticky Footer</footer>
```

> ### Sticky Header & Fixed Footer

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const container = document.querySelector(".card-container");

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.innerText = "Click Me!!";
    container.appendChild(card);
}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        card.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: cursive;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /*Expanding to take full width*/
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header,
footer {
    background: slateblue;
    padding: 1em;
}

.card-container {
    flex: 1; /* IMP */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 0 1em 2em;
    padding-top: 5em; /* IMP */
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: coral;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>Sticky Header & Fixed Footer</header>
<div class="card-container"></div>
<footer>Fixed Footer</footer>
```

> ### Fixed Header & Sticky Footer

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const container = document.querySelector(".card-container");

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.innerText = "Click Me!!";
    container.appendChild(card);
}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        card.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: cursive;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    /*Expanding to take full width*/
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header,
footer {
    background: slateblue;
    padding: 1em;
}

.card-container {
    flex: 1; /* IMP */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: coral;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>Fixed Header & Sticky Footer</header>
<div class="card-container"></div>
<footer>Sticky Footer</footer>
```

> ### Fixed Header & Fixed Footer

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const container = document.querySelector(".card-container");

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.innerText = "Click Me!!";
    container.appendChild(card);
}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        card.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: cursive;
}

header,
footer {
    background: slateblue;
    padding: 1em;
}

.card-container {
    flex: 1; /* IMP */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: coral;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>Fixed Header & Fixed Footer</header>
<div class="card-container"></div>
<footer>Fixed Footer</footer>
```

### Finally the code below is the solution to the updated question

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const container = document.querySelector(".card-container");

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.innerText = "Click Me!!";
    container.appendChild(card);
}

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        card.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header aside" "body aside" "footer aside";

    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: cursive;
}

aside {
    grid-area: aside;
    background: midnightblue;
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
}

footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}

header,
footer {
    background: slateblue;
    padding: 1em;
}

.card-container {
    grid-area: body;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: start;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: coral;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="card-container"></div>
    <aside>Sidebar</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I needed and it works the way you have presented it. What happens though when I incorporate your solution into my already existing divs, the sidebar is now overlapped by the header and the footer. The sidebar should not be overlapped. I tried using divs and them having a class name of header and footer but that didn't work.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap, not sure if this makes a difference. I need the divs to remain as is. I tried adding your code into my className="" of each div but it's not working like it is if I specifically have nav and footer tags.

I have updated my initial post to include some more information as well as an image to hopefully make it easier to visualize what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @KenanBjelosevic Okay I got what you want. I am writing the code for it. Till then I've updated my answer you can take a look

Comment: @KenanBjelosevic I've updated my answer. Last code snippet will hopefully solve your problem, I've used GRID to achieve the layout you wanted. You can accept this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: This is amazing. I didn't expect you to do all of it. Thank you so much for your assistance. Seriously, this has helped a lot.

Can you just explain briefly what these lines of code mean?

const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");

const container = document.querySelector(".card-container")

Is this just to be able to get the styling from the css file?

Comment: This is just for selecting the respective DOM elements. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) The javascript part is basically for adding a bunch of cards, **you can ignore it completely**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229335/discussion-between-kenan-bjelosevic-and-som-shekhar-mukherjee).