# Remove white space when main dont have contents

Tags: html, css

Hi guys im working on the front-end of an angular application and have a problem.
In my dashboard i have header,footer and a main with content ([dashboard without prob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyIVy.png)) but if i click on the link to go in another page the content is short and there is a space under my footer how i can remove it? ill try with `position: fixed; width: 100%; bottom: 0;` but like this in the main page i have the footer ever visible so how can i fix it in another way?[view-job-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGIbB.png)

Header and footer are common 4 all the app.

dashboard html

```
<nav>
  <div class="category-container">
    <label for="cars">Choose a category:</label>

    <select name="category" id="category"  
            [(ngModel)]="userCategoryChoice"
            (ngModelChange)="getUserCategoryChoice()"
            >
            <option *ngFor="let cat of categoryList" [value]="cat">{{cat}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="level-container" *ngFor="let level of levelsList">
      <input type="checkbox" [value]="level.name"
      [checked]="level.selected"
      (change)="onChangeLevel($event)"
      />
      <label for="level">{{level.name}}</label>
  </div>
  
  <button (click)="getUserQuery()">search</button>
</nav>

<main>
  <div class="card-container">

    <div class="card" *ngFor="let jobs of jobListLimited">

      <!-- <p class="custom-overflow" [innerHtml]="jobs.contents"></p> -->
      <!-- <a href="#">Read more...</a> -->
    
      <ul>
        <li class="company-name">{{jobs.name}}</li>
        <li class="jobs-details">Company : {{jobs.company.name}}</li>
        <li class="jobs-details">Location : {{jobs.locations[0].name}}</li>
        <li class="jobs-details">Posted on : {{jobs.publication_date}}</li> <!-- to cut -->
      </ul>

      <div>
        <!-- <button (click)="viewJob()">View job</button> -->
        <button routerLink="/jobs-detail/">View job</button>

      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

dashboard css

```
nav {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

    .category-container {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;

        label {
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }

        select {
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            outline: none;
        }
    }

    .level-container {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;

        input {
            accent-color: #85cadd;
        }

        label {
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
    }

    button {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #85cadd;
        color: white;
    }
}


main {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    .card-container {
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 90px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;

        .card {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 2px solid #c5e4ea;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            background-color: #e8f2f4;
            box-shadow:
            1.8px 4.5px 3.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.024),
            5px 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035),
            12.1px 30.1px 24.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.046),
            40px 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);


            ul {
                padding-top: 10px;
                list-style-type: none;

                .company-name {
                    color: #4783e6;
                }

                .jobs-details {
                    color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
                    font-size: smaller;
                }
            }

            button {
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 10px;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: #4783e6;
                color: white;
            }
        }
        
        // to limit txt
        // .custom-overflow {
        //     text-align: justify;
        //     display: -webkit-box;
        //     -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
        //     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        //     overflow: hidden;
        // }
    }
    
}
```

header html

```
<header>
    <h1>JOBS <span>FINDER</span></h1>
</header>
```

header css

```
header {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;

    h1 {
       text-align: center;
       color: white;

       span {
            color: #85cadd;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Include the code in your question please

Comment: I would suggest using Flexbox. You can look at the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324844/css-flexbox-header-main-footer-layout-main-part-collapsing-in-the-middle).